# How do I force move something when sudo mv -f doesn't work?

Tags: osx, cp, mv

I need to move a 16 GB folder to my external drive, but moving it manually gives me an in use error. I have tried to start in safe mode and moved it but it was still in use.

I have run these commands

```
diskutil repairdisk /dev/disk0s2
diskutil repairdisk /dev/disk2
```

Where disk0 is my disk and disk2 is the one I want to move it to.

I have no permission errors and I have even run `sudo mv -f` it gives me these:

```
mv: symlink: ../../../../../Preferences/com.apple.systemsound.plist: File exists`
```

I have also gotten the same error but without `symlink`

For 200 files and the last error is this

```
mv: /bin/cp: terminated with 1 (non-zero) status
```

What can I do? I have also ran  `sudo chmod 777` for both folders and used the "include for all files option (OS X).

By request here is the exact command:

```
sudo mv -f ~/desktop/collections/jadd /Volumes/External\ 4
```

Comment: Are any of the files over 4gb? What file system is the destination disk?

Comment: Its a "Mac OS Extended (journaled)" and the biggest file is 1,58 GB

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact command you used and the exact error received.

Comment: But the error is over 200 lines?

Comment: Is /Volumes/External\ 4 empty or does it have files (possibly duplicates of what you're trying to move) in it already?

Comment: It does have a duplicate yes, because it moves everything half ways